# What is the correct attribute for a setter/getter for an int?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, getter-setter

I have seen a number of different ways to propertise/synthesize a int, but I don't know the proper way.

I usually do:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt
```

But I have seen people use:

```
@property (nonatomic) int myInt
@property int myInt
```

Which way is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [a great post about the difference between `atomic` and `nonatomic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties):

> Assuming that you are @synthesizing the method implementations, atomic
>   vs. non-atomic changes the generated code. If you are writing your own
>   setter/getters, atomic/nonatomic/retain/assign/copy are merely
>   advisory.
>
> With atomic, the synthesized setter/getter will ensure that a whole
>   value is always returned from the getter or set by the setter,
>   regardless of setter activity on any other thread. That is, if thread
>   A is in the middle of the getter while thread B calls the setter, an
>   actual viable value -- an autoreleased object, most likely -- will be
>   returned to the caller in A.
>
> In nonatomic, no such guarantees are made. Thus, nonatomic is
>   considerably faster than atomic.
>
> What atomic does not do is make any guarantees about thread safety. If
>   thread A is calling the getter simultaneously with thread B and C
>   calling the setter with different values, thread A may get any one of
>   the three values returned -- the one prior to any setters being called
>   or either of the values passed into the setters in B and C. Likewise,
>   the object may end up with the value from B or C, no way to tell.
>
> Ensuring data integrity -- one of the primary challenges of
>   multi-threaded programming -- is achieved by other means.

Note that the default is `atomic`, so the last example is equivalent to

```
@property (atomic) int myInt
```

Another default value is `assign`, therefore these two options are equivalent:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt
@property (nonatomic) int myInt
```

And, similarly, the following are also equivalent

```
@property (atomic, assign) int myInt
@property (atomic) int myInt
```

EDIT: As Josh points out, `atomic` being included is a hypothetical example.

Comment: You might mention that `atomic` does not actually exist as a keyword for properties, so the first and last two examples are hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

defaults are assign and atomic

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a style issue than an issue of technical correctness. For an int type, the only thing that *has* to true the `assign` modifier (because you don't retain scalars). Otherwise, it's context specific: readwrite or readonly, atomic or nonatomic, it depends on the application.

Note that if you don't specify a modifier, the default applies (atomic, readwrite, assign). So your example your first other example are identical, and the third only differs in atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

@property(nonatomic,assign)int myVariable;

always remember assign will be used for primitive data types like int , bool